# Using PrimeFaces' RequestContext to update a component in another page

Tags: ajax, jsf, primefaces

I've discovered PrimeFaces' `RequestContext#update` and I've found it very useful.

Now I want it to update a component that's NOT on the page who called the bean.

Is there any way to tell to `RequestContext#update` that the component that need to be updated is on another page?

Something like : `RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().update("downloads.xhtml", ":downloadPanel")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's only possible if you navigate back to exactly that page when the action method finishes. It makes otherwise no sense anyway as the `RequestContext` applies to the current request only.