# Primefaces update component on another page

Tags: hibernate, jsf, primefaces

I added a value to the db and the current page's component is updated successfully through the UPDATE="client_id_of_the_component"
Now, i want to update some component present on another page to be updated.
Like, i've country db table. Now on another page, i'm using all the countries in the dropdown list. Now, when somebody adds a new country, i want the p:selectonemenu of the primefaces to be updated (which is on another page).

How to do it ? 
Thanks

Comment: Make sure that you other page is view or request scope... that way the data from that "next" page will be always up to date, if the beans are session scoped you can use managed property...

Comment: check this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10615815/using-primefaces-requestcontext-to-update-a-component-in-another-page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the PrimeFaces Poll component to do an ajax request every X number of seconds to check for changes that should be applied to the dropdown.